# How to restrict FCM push notification to application id?

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have created a project in firebase and created two android applications inside.

But if I send push notification with Admin SDK, notification goes to both applications, how can we restrict notification to single package only?

My notification format is as below:

```
var message = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Test title',
      body: 'Test body',
    },

    android: {
      ttl: 3600 * 1000,
      notification: {
        icon: 'test_icon',
        color: '#f45342',
      },
    },
    topic: topic
  };
```

Comment: [restricted_package_name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) MayBe..

Comment: @ADM What about iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ADM for hint.
We can use restricted_package_name and specify our app id in order for restricting push notification for particular app.

Message format should be this:

```
var message = {

    notification: {
      title: 'Test title',
      body: 'Test body'
    },

    android: {
      restricted_package_name: "com.mycompany.someapp",
      notification: {
        icon: 'test_icon',
        color: '#f45342',
      },
    },

    topic: topic
  };
```

It should be inside the android key since restricted_package_name is only available to android.

Comment: yes `restricted_package_name`, that would resolve the issue.

Comment: @Prajeet Shreshtha what about iOS? Can we restrict the same as well